# Target child div of app container with CSS

Tags: css, angular

So I am building a website using Angular.
I then have some code that looks something like this:

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="container">
      <app-name>
         <div class="app-child-div"></div>
      </app-name>
   </div>
</div>
```

And I am told that the `app-name` name can actually change when deployed. So I am not entirely sure that the name will remain the same. However, using SCSS, how can I target the `app-child-div` with CSS ?

Right now I am doing something like this:

```
.main {

    .container {

        app-step-0 {

            .app-child-div {
                background: green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to do the trick. So is there anything I can do?

Comment: Just remove `app-step-0`

Comment: What if I actually wish to apply CSS on the <app> itself ? Is that possible ?

Comment: Have you tried `<app-name class="app-name-wrapper">` and then `.app-name-wrapper {}`?

Comment: I'm an idiot. Of course you can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some attribute (e.g. class) that will identify your element.

E.g. add class for it:

```html
<div class="main">
   <div class="container">
      <app-name class="app-name-wrapper">
         <div class="app-child-div"></div>
      </app-name>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then use this `.app-name-wrapper` in CSS